# What is the difference between \somecmd and \csname somecmd\endcsname?

Tags: soul, csname

This is a demo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname {#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else #1 not defined \fi%
}
\makeatother

\def\test{some text to complete}
\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}
\ul\test                 % it works
%%%% if uncomment, the below one does not work, an error is reported 
% \ul\mygetdef{xxx}
\end{document}
```

As the comment says, if `\ul\mygetdef{xxx}` takes place, there comes a error:

! Argument of \SOUL@@ has an extra }.

**UPDATE:**

I switch to package `ulem` where `\uline` can underline `\fbox`.
Everything works (see MWE below).
Then I try to make colorful box.
However, I find that once I include package `xcolor` or `tcolorbox` (as the comment in MWE), some weird error comes up immediately even before I actually use them in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%% uncomment either of the packages below, it reports errors.
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname {#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else \protect\fbox{#1} \fi%
}

\def\test{some text to complete}
\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}
\uline{\test}

\edef\mytmp{\mygetdef{xxx}}
\uline{\mytmp}

\edef\mytmp{\mygetdef{yyy}}
\uline{\mytmp}

\end{document}
```

After all my efforts, I can not figure out why and solve it.
So I updated my original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\edef\tmp{\mygetdef{xxx}}
\ul\tmp
```

The `\mygetdef` needs to be expanded before being passed to `\ul`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname {#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else #1 not defined \fi%
}
\makeatother

\def\test{some text to complete}
\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}
\ul\test                 % it works
%%%% if uncomment, the below one does not work, an error is reported 
% \ul\mygetdef{xxx}

\edef\tmp{\mygetdef{xxx}}
\ul\tmp
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENTAL NOTE TO OP**

Not really to answer OP question, but in reply to some of his comments to this answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname {#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else
#1 not defined \fi%
}
\newcommand{\myulgetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \expandafter\ul{\csname my#1\endcsname}%
  \else\fbox{#1 not defined} \fi%
}
\newcommand{\myxgetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \expandafter\csname my#1\endcsname%
  \else\protect\protect\protect\fbox{#1 not defined} \fi%
}
\newcommand\exul[1]{\edef\tmp{#1}\ul\tmp}
\makeatother

\def\test{some text to complete}
\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}
\ul\test                 % it works

\exul{\mygetdef{xxx}}

1. \mygetdef{yyy}

2. \myulgetdef{yyy}

3. \myxgetdef{yyy}

4. \exul{\mygetdef{yyy}}

5. \exul{\myxgetdef{yyy}}% HOWEVER, \fbox IS NOT UNDERLINED

%6. \exul{\myulgetdef{yyy}}% FAILS; CANNOT \ul{\fbox{...}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way putting `\edef` part in `\mygetdef` to make it work?

Comment: @jiewuza It would be easier to define `\newcommand\exul[1]{\edef\tmp{#1}\ul\tmp}` and then invoke it as `\exul{\mygetdef{xxx}}`.

Comment: Well, then I have to define more `\newcommand` for others besides `\ul`. But it works anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: I just got another problem. I added `\fbox` in `\mygetdef`, that is, `\ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else \fbox{#1 not defined} \fi`. And when I try  `\mygetdef{yyy}` (which is not defined), it brokes with some `Undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: @jiewuza  The command `\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
    \ifcsname my#1\endcsname \csname my#1\endcsname \else
\fbox{ #1 not defined} \fi%
}` works just fine if invoked directly as `\mygetdef{yyy}`.  However, `\exul{\mygetdef{yyy}}` does not work in that case because you can't `\ul` an `\fbox`.

Comment: @jiewuza Please see my edited answer where I try to show what I mean in the prior comment.

Comment: I switched to `\uline` which can underline `\fbox`. But I found some weird problem with your solution when I am trying to bring in `xcolor`. I edited my original question. Please have a look and help me out.

Comment: @jiewuza In such cases, it is better to ask a new question.  Look at the effort egreg put in to answer the question about `\ul`.  To change the question to be about the `ulem` package at this point is not fair to those who have already helped.

Comment: Fair enough. I would ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\ul` is defined as `\SOUL@ulsetup\SOUL@`. The first command sets up some commands that will be later delivered after a group has started and is of no concern here.

The macro `\SOUL@` is defined as

```latex
% soul.sty, line 99:
\def\SOUL@{%
    \futurelet\SOUL@@\SOUL@expand
}
```

which means that the following token is looked up and stored in `\SOUL@@`; then `\SOUL@expand` is executed

```latex
% soul.sty, line 102:
\def\SOUL@expand{%
    \ifcat\bgroup\noexpand\SOUL@@
        \let\SOUL@n\SOUL@start
    \else
        \bgroup
            \def\\##1##2{\def##2{\noexpand##2}}%
            \the\SOUL@cmds
            \SOUL@buffer={%
                \\\TeX\\\LaTeX\\\soulomit\\\mbox\\\hbox\\\textregistered
                \\\slash\\\textcircled\\\copyright\\\S\\\,\\\<\\\>\\~%
                \\\\%
            }%
            \def\\##1{\def##1{\noexpand##1}}%
            \the\SOUL@buffer
            \let\protect\noexpand
            \xdef\SOUL@n##1{\noexpand\SOUL@start{\SOUL@@}}%
        \egroup
    \fi
    \SOUL@n
}
```

Quite a mouthful! The behavior depends on whether the token stored in `\SOUL@@` is a left brace or not. In your case it isn't.

The part of the code above which is of primary interest is

```latex
            \let\protect\noexpand
            \xdef\SOUL@n##1{\noexpand\SOUL@start{\SOUL@@}}%
```

Note that `\SOUL@@` is the token found at the first step, in your case `\mygetdef`. At the end, `\SOUL@n` is executed, which discards the next token (your `\mygetdef`) and does

```latex
\SOUL@start{<full expansion of \mygetdef`>}
```

The place where the error happens is at the `\xdef`, because `\mygetdef` does not find its argument, but just the closing brace. What you want is that

```latex
\ul\mygetdef{xxx}
```

becomes

```latex
\ul\myxxx
```

You need to do some clever expansion for this, but it becomes very awkward, mainly because of the conditionals. If you do

```latex
\expandafter\ul\myxxx
```

you get

```latex
\ul\ifcsname myxxx\endcsname\csname myxxx\endcsname\else xxx not defined \fi
```

With three `\expandafter`s

```latex
\ul\csname myxxx\endcsname\else xxx not defined \fi
```

With seven `\expandafter`s

```latex
\ul\myxxx\else xxx not defined \fi
```

That's it! Let's see what happens with `\mygetdef{noway}` (assuming it's undefined). You'd get

```latex
\ul noway not defined \fi
```

which is not really what you want, but can be easily fixed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname my#1\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[1]{%
  \ifcsname my#1\endcsname
    \csname my#1\endcsname
  \else
   {}#1 not defined%
  \fi
}

\def\test{some text to complete}
\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}

\ul\test

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\ul\mygetdef{xxx}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\ul\mygetdef{noway}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My proposal is to define differently `\mygetdef`, if you plan to use it after `soul` macros, but not only.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mydef}[2]{%
  \@namedef{my#1}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\mygetdef}[2][\relax]{%
  \@ifundefined{my#2}%
    {{}#2 not defined}%
    {\expandafter#1\csname my#2\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\mydef{xxx}{some text to complete}

\begin{document}

\mygetdef{xxx}

\mygetdef[\ul]{xxx}

\mygetdef[\textit]{xxx}

\mygetdef[\ul]{noway}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although it is now beyond my understanding, your explanation is really helpful.  I am learning the expanding rules. And your redefination of `\mygetdef` is quite interesting. I will dig more.